# jQuery extend - target object don't get extended

Tags: jquery, extend

```
var collection = $('ul li');
collection.each(function (index) {
    var test = $.extend($(this), {
    // var test = $.extend(collection.eq(index), {
        someProperty: 'val'
    });
    console.log(test.someProperty);
});
console.log(collection.eq(0).someProperty);
```

And the test: http://jsfiddle.net/simo/G3yCr/1/

I'm trying to extend each object inside a jquery collection. I want to access the properties directly from each item inside the collection.

The question is why the `collection.eq(index)` object don't get extended. The commented line is alternative and gives the same results.

The spec: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/

Comment: You're extending a jQuery instance (that is what `$(this)` returns) - and this instance gets vanished once the each-callback has finished. So you're not actually extending "collection".

Comment: Ok, but the test fails even with the commented line below: `var test = $.extend(collection.eq(index)` don't get extended too?

Comment: @simo `collection.eq(index)` _also_ creates a new jQuery object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `.each` function `this` is referring to the individual DOM elements from the collection, and not to a jQuery object.

When you then call `$(this)` you're creating a *new* jQuery object, it's not the one from the collection.

The easiest way to make this additional property persist would be to add it to the element itself.  Alternatively use `.data()` to store and retrieve the additional properties.

On ES5 browsers you can then use a (possibly nasty) hack to make your `.data()` look like a real property:

```
(function($) {
    Object.defineProperty($.fn, 'foo', {
        get: function() {
            return $(this).data('foo');
        },
        set: function(v) {
            $(this).data('foo', v);
        }
    });
})(jQuery);

$('#d1').foo = 'bar';
$('#d2').foo = 'wot';

alert([$('#d1').foo, $('#d2').foo]);
```

Note that (AFAIK) no other jQuery code adds properties (other than `.length)` on a jQuery object.  Use of this trick may confuse other developers.

Comment: To elaborate a bit: The actual element is only available via the "fake-array" syntax `collection[index]` (not via `eq(index)`!) - http://jsfiddle.net/G3yCr/2/

Comment: Yes I know that this works but I wanted to access the object like this: `collection.eq(0).prop` not `collection.eq(0)[0].prop`

Comment: @simo you need to use `.data('prop')` instead, then.  You _might_ be able to add a dynamic property to `$.fn` which automatically reads the desired `.data()` value.

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Just read up on [jQuery Plugin Authoring](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring):

```
$.fn.someProperty = 'val';
var collection = $('ul li');
console.log(collection.eq(0).someProperty);​
```

No iteration through the whole collection is necessary.

Comment: this will give _every_ jQuery object the same value for that property, which is rather pointless...

Comment: Indeed… however from the example in the question I understood that's exactly what the author is after.